# Global variables in override controller MY_Controller in CodeIgiter 3.1.9

Tags: codeigniter-3

**This question is about CodeIgniter 3.1.9**

I override the CI_Controller with MY_Controller according to [this page](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html).

I wonder if I can create a variable in the constructor of MY_Controller that would be accessible everywhere else in the project (Controllers, Models, Views, Libraries ...)

Sessions will do the job but will not be the best options, since variables will be keep from one page to another.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is make your library to deal with thing and it can be access by: $this->*your_library*

[take look here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html)